# Upvoting good questions

Tags: discussion

Here on biology.SE my impression is that people do not upvote good questions as readily as on other SE sites.
• Is this just a habit? Do we need to encourage upvoting good questions? Is the exisiting "Suffrage" badge enough for this?
• Are questions of poor quality here?
• Or do you think this is OK?

Comment: As a newcomer, I have not actually noticed this - the upvoting seems to be on a par with other sites I frequent.  I could be wrong though, as I have not been a member here for long.

Comment: @DamienIgoe: Yesterday I went through multiple pages of zero-vote questions and found many interesting and well phrased ones.

Comment: @winerd Could you provide links to a couple of questions that fit this bill into your question?

Comment: I have to say that all of my questions and my answer have been upvoted (not sure if they are good), but recognition is certainly given.

Comment: +1, partially due the screaming irony (currently zero votes) and partially because I've been thinking the same thing (sometimes also for answers).

Answer (score 4):

I answer Rory M's comment here, I made a little research.

Today page 160* of the questions ordered by the decreasing number of votes consisted of the following. I judged them as I indicated below according to the criteria that pop up when the mouse pointer is over the upvote button.

1. [Eye Brain Mapping](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8875/eye-brain-mapping) -- Shows research effort? Unsure. Interesting for biology.SE? Yes. Clear? Reasonably. -- I upvoted it.
2. [Is it possible to selectively breed carnivorous animals, like tigers, to be herbivores?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8869/is-it-possible-to-selectively-breed-carnivorous-animals-like-tigers-to-be-herb) -- Shows research effort? Unsure. Interesting for biology.SE? Yes. Clear? Acceptably. -- I upvoted it.
3. [Multiple Systems Atrophy - clinical trials [closed]](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8854/multiple-systems-atrophy-clinical-trials)
4. [Information Gene HBA2](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8824/information-gene-hba2) -- Shows research effort? Yes. Interesting for biology.SE? Maybe. Clear? Acceptably. -- I did not upvote it.
5. [Why do antacids have a special importance when taking lactulose?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8807/why-do-antacids-have-a-special-importance-when-taking-lactulose) -- I skipped this because this is my own question.
6. [Understanding SIR models in epidemiology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8781/understanding-sir-models-in-epidemiology) -- Shows research effort? Yes. Interesting for biology.SE? Maybe. Clear? No. -- I did not upvote it.
7. [Polymorphism in cnidarians?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8745/polymorphism-in-cnidarians) -- Shows research effort? Some. Interesting for biology.SE? Yes. Clear? Reasonably. -- I upvoted it.
8. [Structure of adenoids](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8738/structure-of-adenoids) -- Shows research effort? Yes. Interesting for biology.SE? Yes. Clear? Yes. -- I did not upvote it because the phrasing is excessively long. However after re-phrasing the question by the author or someone else to a concise form I would probably upvote it.
9. [Avian Diseases : How to Disinfect](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8677/avian-diseases-how-to-disinfect) -- Shows research effort? Some. Interesting for biology.SE? Yes. Clear? Yes, after the comment from the author. -- I upvoted it.
10. [Do chloroplasts contain circular DNA? If so, why? [duplicate]](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8602/do-chloroplasts-contain-circular-dna-if-so-why)
11. [Do women feel pain the same exact way as men do?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8596/do-women-feel-pain-the-same-exact-way-as-men-do) -- Shows research effort? Yes. Interesting for biology.SE? Yes. Clear? Yes, after the edit. -- I upvoted it.
12. [What is this genital infection?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8581/what-is-this-genital-infection) -- Shows research effort? Yes. Interesting for biology.SE? Yes. Clear? Yes. -- However, I did not upvote it as only the answer will be able to decide if this is a question of public interest or not.
13. [Ligase Chain Reaction: Determining the annealing temperature for gene synthesis](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8569/ligase-chain-reaction-determining-the-annealing-temperature-for-gene-synthesis) -- I skipped this because I know too little about this topic.
14. [Skeletal muscles in clam](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8554/skeletal-muscles-in-clam) -- Shows research effort? Maybe. Interesting for biology.SE? Yes. Clear? Yes. -- I upvoted it, because I would be interested in the answer. In the same time I exclude this from my summary, as this may indeed be a homework.
15. [Are there precedents for considering that the coral reef biome has higher biodiversity than rain forests?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/8547/are-there-precedents-for-considering-that-the-coral-reef-biome-has-higher-biodiv) -- Shows research effort? Yes. Interesting for biology.SE? Yes. Clear? Important details missing. -- I didn't upvote it.

**Summary**

I processed a random sample of 15 questions. I excluded 4 of them because of the following reasons: closed, duplicate, my own question; and included 11 in the analysis. I upvoted 6 questions (55%), did not upvote 5 (45%).

The research has strengthened my previous opinion that here on biology.SE good questions are often not upvoted.

​* a randomly chosen page with zero vote questions

Comment: Excellent analysis.  A few points I would raise as possible explanations are that compared to other SE sites we are still growing, therefore there may not be as many regular users to give upvotes.  Alternatively it could be because people feel more comfortable voting in their own field (a la Stack Overflow), though I think at this point we're not a sizeable enough community to encourage this practise and (whilst I don't vote on answers that I'm not 100% sure I understand) it shouldn't affect questions to the same degree anyway.

Comment: Just as an educational point for some site functions, you might have found it easier to use the advanced search functions.  Something like `score:0 closed:no`

Comment: I have been wondering if as a general statement, SE's that are more populated with actual researches are less likely to up vote.  I feel it could be related to our increased certainty in uncertainty.